# Binding doesn't refresh if path used

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

In my MainWindow I have an ObservableCollection which is shown in a Listbox per Binding.

If I update my Collection the modification is shown in the list.

This works:

```
public ObservableCollection<double> arr = new ObservableCollection<double>();

public MainWindow()
{
            arr.Add(1.1);
            arr.Add(2.2);
            testlist.DataContext = arr;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   arr[0] += 1.0;
}
<ListBox Name="testlist" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListBox>
```

This version works not:

```
public ObservableCollection<double> arr = new ObservableCollection<double>();

public MainWindow()
{
            arr.Add(1.1);
            arr.Add(2.2);
            testlist.DataContext = this;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   arr[0] += 1.0;
}
<ListBox Name="testlist" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=arr}"></ListBox>
```

Can you tell me why?
I would like to give *this* as the DataContext, because there are many other properties to show in my dialog and it would be nice if I wouldn't have to set the DataContext for every individual control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expose your collection as a property, right now it's a field. So make arr private again and add:

```
public ObservableCollection<double> Arr {
    get {
        return this.arr;
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to bind like `{Binding Path=Arr}`, assuming `this` is the current DataContext.

Answer (score 4):

You can't bind to a field, only to a property.  Try wrapping `arr` in a property and you should find it works fine.